# How to restore emails from deleted email account in Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird, imap

I recently graduated from college and have lost access to my school email account.

However, I accidently deleted my school email account from Thunderbird. Fortunately, I haven't checked the option to delete emails stored in my local device.

I can locate stored emails in Thunderbird profile folder. However, I can't add same email account in Thunderbird since I cannot pass authentication - technically the account does not exist any more.

All I have is .msf file and corresponding folder that contains my inbox and sent emails. I want to show them on Thunderbird again. How can I restore them?

Here are what I have tried:

- I copied both .msf file and folder to "Local Folders" folder. The Local Folder account shows the name of the folder moved, but no contents to be shown.
- I tried to create new connection of Thunderbird and dummy email account and replaced the contents of deleted email account. Didn't work as I expected.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Check the Recycle Bin for `.msf` files. For each one there is another with the same name but without any extension.

Comment: @harrymc I have the files. Inside the folder with same name of `.msf` file there are files without extentions like `INBOX` and `SENT`, I just want to display them on Thunerbird again.

Comment: Do you have the entire profile as before the deletion? If yes, close Thunderbird and return the profile, and the rest is automatic.

Comment: @harrymc I did as your advice. However the email account doesn't return.

Comment: Is your backup truly from before you removed the account?

Comment: The files in which TB stores the emails (such as `INBOX`...) are pure text files that can open with any text editor and recognize the emails. Did you try? That's definitely not a easy way to read the emails, but at least this to check that there is indeed someting to recover (or not)...

Comment: By the wat, the `.msf` files are also text files that you can open to check what they contain.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution might be to create a new "dummy" account as you did previously, but then to try importing your old messages. In TB, go to `Tools > Import...` to import.

Import operation(s) shouldn't effect the data at all. But being the ultra-paranoid type, I'd recommend making a copy of the folder containing all of your old messages as insurance against disaster.